# PhoneGap iOS oAuth redirect failing (NSURLErrorDomain error -999.)

Tags: cordova, oauth, meteor

MeteorJS: https://github.com/zeroasterisk/Presenteract

PhoneGap: https://github.com/zeroasterisk/Presenteract-PhoneGap-ios

- I am running a MeteorJS application inside PhoneGap 2.7 on iOS.
- The MeteorJS application is loaded via an external URL, setup in `config.xml` as the `<content src="http://presenteract.meteor.com" />`
- I have no problems with oAuth from within a browser
- The `access` config is setup with a full wildcard `<access origin="*" />`
- The application works very well, identical to the browser version of it....

But when I attempt oAuth from within PhoneGap, I end up with the following error:

```
Failed to load webpage with error: The operation couldn’t be completed.
(NSURLErrorDomain error -999.)
```

*(NOTE: oAuth attempts from Google, Facebook, and Twitter are all the same.  Loads external site, login proceeds as normal, and upon redirect back to my application's main URL)*

I have looked through other StackOverflow reports and done some googeling... The most useful one I found is:

[Facebook dialog failed with error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -999.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8979610/facebook-dialog-failed-with-error-the-operation-couldnt-be-completed-nsurler)
*& Related: [NSURLErrorDomain error -999 - links failing in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10920518/nsurlerrordomain-error-999-links-failing-in-ios)*

This seems very promising, but I don't know how to translate this solution into PhoneGap...

I Found the following stub, in `<projectname>/Classes/MainViewController.m` and I have played with it a bit, but to no solution yet....

```
- (void) webView:(UIWebView*)theWebView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError*)error
{
    /* (this does log to the console, but doesn't tell me anything different)
    * still: theWebView webView didFailLoadWithError:NSURLErrorDomain -999
    */
    NSLog(@"theWebView webView didFailLoadWithError:%@ %d",error.domain,error.code);

    /* (this is commented out, it didn't seem to do anything for me) */
    if ([error.domain isEqualToString:@"NSURLErrorDomain"] && error.code == -999) {
        NSLog(@"theWebView webView caught the error=-999... but returning void doesn't force the page to reload/continue:%@ %d",error.domain,error.code);
        return;
    }

    /* (this was already here, part of PhoneGap) */
    return [super webView:theWebView didFailLoadWithError:error];
}
```

I get the second "caught the error=-999" log message, but I end up in a white screen on the app still.

- Perhaps there's some setting somewhere to allow the redirect-back to my application's URL?
- Perhaps I need to force it to reload my app's main page?
- Perhaps I need some more elegant way of catching the error so that it doesn't stop loading?
- Perhaps I need more information about what was causing the failure in the first place?

Answer (score 2):

I hit the same error when I upgraded from Cordova (PhoneGap) 2.2 to 2.7.

Looking at your description, I cannot readily tell if it is the same problem. But, I thought sharing my solution / workaround might help.

The problem I hit was that Cordova 2.7 didn't handle client side redirect during startup correctly.

I also tried to play around `MainViewController.m`, but I didn't believe the problem can be worked around there.

My solution was to modified `CordovaLib/Classes/CDVWebViewDelegate.m` to handle the redirect case.

Here is my pull-request:

https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/pull/57/files

Comment: awesome - thanks for sharing, i will review as soon as I'm able!  (I'm toying with the idea of "downgrading" PhoneGap until resolved, as I have a different plugin issue too)

Comment: The bug is fixed for Phonegap 3.0.