# PhoneGap + iOS: NSURLErrorDomain error -999

Tags: ios, cordova, nsurlerrordomain

I am currently having issues running a Cordova 3.5.0 application in iOS. The app seems to run just fine in Chrome, in Safari and in Android devices, but when I try to run it in an iPad, it crashes. On running it in any of the XCode simulators, I get the following:

```
2014-06-30 10:16:07.737 MyApp[4459:60b] Multi-tasking -> Device: YES, App: YES
2014-06-30 10:16:07.743 MyApp[4459:60b] Unlimited access to network resources
2014-06-30 10:16:07.956 MyApp[4459:60b] Resetting plugins due to page load.
2014-06-30 10:16:08.094 MyApp[4459:60b] Failed to load webpage with error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -999.)
2014-06-30 10:16:08.098 MyApp[4459:60b] Resetting plugins due to page load.
2014-06-30 10:16:08.213 MyApp[4459:60b] Finished load of: file:///Users/ESS/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/7.1-64/Applications/CAFC31D8-D2B1-44C0-BB6F-8ACF64A91DB5/MyApp.app/www/plugins.html
```

Now, the problem seems to happen whenever I redirect the user from one page to another using window.location.href="something.html". Is there any way in which I can prevent this issue from happening? Someone [in here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16441984/phonegap-ios-oauth-redirect-failing-nsurlerrordomain-error-999) had the same issue yet but it seems to have been fixed since the version 3.0.0 and I'm using 3.5.0.

Does anyone have any idea as to how work around this issue?

Comment: I suspect your redirect is happening before a current webView load request has completed. Two typical ways to handle this...1) modify your init code to handle the setting of a preferred startPage prior to webView load, or 2) cancel the current webView load prior to the redirect.

Comment: I'll have to look into that. The problem is that I'm using PhoneGap and, as such, I don't work directly with webViews; instead, I would expect the framework to do the work for me. But I might need to resort to a different approach or simply edit PhoneGap's code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the crash didn't have anything to do with NSURLErrorDomain. I managed to avoid NSURLErrorDomain by waiting a certain time before redirecting the user to a different page, yet the app kept crashing. It turns out that the NSURLErrorDomain is benign in Cordova and the issue was somewhere else in my code.